# Text cannot be written in multiple lines in EditText

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

`EditText` has strange behavior. Whatever I write in it is written in only **single line**. I am not able write text in a second line (new line).

Why I cannot write text in multiple lines?

Here's my `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tbr_des"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/des"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:maxLength="300"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"/>
```

Whereas my another activity has same `EditText` with all same attributes, and it lets me write in multiple lines. I'm using `LinearLayout` in both xml.

`EditText` of another layout.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/des"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:maxLength="300"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"/>
```

I also tried `android:singleLine="false"` but doesn't work.

Comment: both layout are same?

Comment: @SurenderKumar no no both are not same, they only have same `edittext`

Comment: @SurenderKumar don't judge it by `layout_height=match_parent`. I have other components too in both layout.

Comment: this " android:inputType="textCapSentences"" thing is extra in your 1st edit text remove this and try.

Comment: @SurenderKumar wait I try in a second

Comment: Welcome dude...its ok ..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `textCapSentences|textMultiLine` as its `inputType`

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    ... />
```

Comment: Awesome Man! It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: don't know why it worked, but just worked for me. Was going mad for this for last 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

By default all the **EditText** widgets in Android are multi-lined.

Here is some sample code:

```
<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
android:gravity="top|left" <!-- Cursor Position -->
android:maxLines="10" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height determined by content -->
android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!-- Fill entire width -->
android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar -->
/>
```

Comment: I'm not getting you, could you say explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs due to

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

if you remove this your code will work fine as you expected.